# React Jest + RTL useRef offSetHeight is not mocking value

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

My Code Coverage is not 100% with below component just because useRef mock is not working

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
...
const textRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState<number>(0);
....
const imageOnLoadHandler = (
  event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLImageElement, Event>
) => {
  setImageHeight(event.currentTarget.height / 2);
};
.....
{children &&
   imageHeight !== 0 &&
   textRef.current &&
   textRef.current.offsetHeight < imageHeight && (
   <div className="text__inner">
      {children}
   </div>
)}
```

In component.test.tsx

```
const useRefMock = jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef');
it('Checking useRef', () => {
   const mockOffsetHeight = 20;
   const mockRef = { current: { offsetHeight: mockOffsetHeight } };

   useRefMock.mockReturnValueOnce(mockRef);
   const ComposedStoryToRender = composeStory(Component, Meta);
   const { container } = render(<ComposedStoryToRender />);
   expect(container).not.toBeNull();

   waitFor(() => {
     expect(
      container.querySelector('.text__inner')
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  // Clear the mock after the test
  useRefMock.mockClear();
});
```